# Fresh install java -version displays nothing

Tags: windows-server-2003, java

I'm attempting to rebuild a legacy application environment. The specs are

- Windows Server 2003 SP2
- Java SDK 1.3.1_15
- Macromedia JRun4

I've installed the Java SDK however whilst attempting to install JRun4, I receive this message during the "JVM Selection" stage

[image: suitable JRE could not be located]

I figured there was something weird with the reported version and when running `c:\jdk1.3.1_15\jre\bin\java.exe -version`, I receive absolutely nothing.

The only way I've been able to get a version displayed is by running `c:\jdk1.3.1_15\jre\bin\java.exe -classic -version`

```
C:\>jdk1.3.1_15\jre\bin\java -version

C:\>jdk1.3.1_15\jre\bin\java -classic -version
java version "1.3.1_15"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.3.1_15-b01)
Classic VM (build 1.3.1_15-b01, native threads, nojit)
```

I have this exact JDK installed on another machine and the version information displays correctly.

Has anybody seen this before and knows something I'm obviously missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No support! This is what Oracle (former Sun) states on their website:

> On Windows, Linux, Solaris 9, and Solaris 10  J2SE 1.3.1 has completed the Sun End of Life (EOL) process. The EOL transition period was from Oct 25, 2004 until the General Availability (GA) of Java SE 6 on December 11th, 2006. With this notice, customers are strongly encouraged to migrate to the current release, Java SE 6.

And even Java SE 6 has a new successor called Java 7. Your version is about 10 years old and the support stopped five years ago.

**Edit**:

Besides that, JRun does not require a full Java JDK it can run only with the JRE. And it is said, that version 1.3 is the *minimum* required version. Newer versions are possible and even recommended due to the fact that the Just-In-Time compiler was optimized for speed in newer versions.

Comment: No. Only that JRun4 doesn't require the Java JDK but can also run with the Java JRE. And maybe your servers differ in the fact that the functioning one is 32bit and the failing is 64bit.

Comment: Both servers are 32 bit. All I'm attempting to do is install the same environment on the new machine. I'll take a closer look at production and see if there's another JRE on the machine that was used for JRun. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Nailed it! The production server also had the 1.4.2 JRE which is what JRun was installed against. Could you add your comment to your answer so I can accept it?